# Flutter provider color isn't change

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

My requirement is based on the system theme mode color will change dynamically. When the System theme is dark the primary color will be light green. When the System theme is light the primary color will be dark blue.
The model I used for the theme

```
class AppThemeData {
  Color primaryColor;
  Color secondaryColor;
  AppThemeData({
     required this.primaryColor,
     required this.secondaryColor,
  });
}
```

The theme variable I used

```
AppThemeData darkModeTheme = AppThemeData(
    primaryColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 9, 230, 127),
    secondaryColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 179),
);
AppThemeData lightModeTheme = AppThemeData(
    primaryColor: const Color(0xFF796BFF),
    secondaryColor: const Color(0xFFFF3D00),
);
```

Provider class function code

```
class AppTheme with ChangeNotifier {
    static var brightness = SchedulerBinding.instance!.window.platformBrightness;
    static bool _isDarkMode = brightness == Brightness.dark;
    static AppThemeData _theme =
        _isDarkMode == true ? darkModeTheme : lightModeTheme;

    bool get isDarkMode => _isDarkMode;
    AppThemeData get theme => _theme;

    changeAppThemeMode(bool appIsDarkMode) {
    _isDarkMode = appIsDarkMode;
    _isDarkMode == true ? _theme = darkModeTheme : _theme = lightModeTheme;
    notifyListeners();
    return "theme";
    }
}
```

Simple Widget I use the Container

```
Container(
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    color: Provider.of<AppTheme>(context, listen: false).theme.primaryColor
)
```

When Brightness changes automatically function will execute

```
@override
void didChangePlatformBrightness() {
  var brightness = SchedulerBinding.instance!.window.platformBrightness;
  bool isDarkMode = brightness == Brightness.dark;

  setState(() {
    Provider.of<AppTheme>(context, listen: false)
        .changeAppThemeMode(isDarkMode);
  });

  widget.onBrightnessChanged?.call();
  super.didChangePlatformBrightness();
}
```

App ThemeData I called like this

```
MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: 'Find Pic',
  theme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    primarySwatch: buildMaterialColor(Provider.of<AppTheme>(context, listen: true).theme.primaryColor)),
  darkTheme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    primarySwatch: buildMaterialColor(Provider.of<AppTheme>(context, listen:true).theme.primaryColor)),
  themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
  home: const MyHomePage(),
);
```

buildMaterialColor function convert Colors to MaterialColor my

```
MaterialColor buildMaterialColor(Color color) {
  List strengths = <double>[.05];
  Map<int, Color> swatch = <int, Color>{};
  final int r = color.red, g = color.green, b = color.blue;

  for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    strengths.add(0.1 * i);
  }
  for (var strength in strengths) {
    final double ds = 0.5 - strength;
    swatch[(strength * 1000).round()] = Color.fromRGBO(
      r + ((ds < 0 ? r : (255 - r)) * ds).round(),
      g + ((ds < 0 ? g : (255 - g)) * ds).round(),
      b + ((ds < 0 ? b : (255 - b)) * ds).round(),
      1,
    );
  }
  return MaterialColor(color.value, swatch);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you've forgotten to initialize the widget's instance as an observer of `WidgetsBindingObserver`. It should be like the following by overriding `initState` and `dispose` methods.

[Live demo on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=b5a65b52b534606406d3db1b660065e9)

```dart
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangePlatformBrightness() {
    var brightness = SchedulerBinding.instance.window.platformBrightness;
    bool isDarkMode = brightness == Brightness.dark;

    setState(() {
      Provider.of<AppTheme>(context, listen: false)
          .changeAppThemeMode(isDarkMode);
    });

    widget.onBrightnessChanged?.call();
    super.didChangePlatformBrightness();
  }

  ...
```

Comment: I use WidgetsBindingObserver but still face this issue

Comment: Weird. The solution works at least on macOS. Which platform are you testing it?

Comment: no, I use the windows system

Comment: I've tested it on both Windows 10 and Windows 11 and even on the web and it works as expected. Please take a look at the [live demo on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=b5a65b52b534606406d3db1b660065e9) and compare it with what you have. Something must be missing.

Comment: When I use listen: true. Container(
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    color: Provider.of<AppTheme>(context, listen: true).theme.primaryColor
);
is working